# 301 redirect from free host (tripod)

Tags: client-side, http-status-code-301

I'm updating a very old website - c.1999 - hosted at Tripod. What I can't figure out is how to do 301 redirects (or 302) on PDFs and Word DOCs there.

To the best of my knowledge I can't use rel=canonical or meta refresh with PDFs and DOCs. Tripod has mod_asis but this appears useless if I can't change mime type.

What client-side options are there for redirecting PDFs and DOCs???

Answer (score 0):

DOC and PDF files can be converted to DOCX and SVG respectively, which would enable the redirect to work if they are embedded in an XHTML or HTML5 document. Here are some tools which may help:

- [WordDown](http://code.google.com/p/jischtml5/wiki/WordDown)
- [PDF2SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120567/convert-pdf-to-svg)