# PDF to SVG, SVG to Raphael Objects

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, raphael, psd

I have searched around and can't seem to find what I am looking for so I am hoping someone here can help me find it or just tell me that its not possible unless I want to write my own. I am trying to import a PDF and convert that PDF to SVG and then convert that SVG to Raphael Objects, or obviously just convert the PDF into Raphael objects.

The designer also wants to be able to upload Adobe PSD, and Adobe AI documents as well. I googled and pretty sure that is not possible but wanted to see if you guys had any input on the situation.

I already have code that takes in an SVG document and converts those objects into Raphael objects. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks all

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert pdf to svg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120567/convert-pdf-to-svg)

Comment: checked that out. not what I was looking for at all. I know inkscape can do it but I need to do this through javascript.